# Navigation drawer fragment place my activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am very new to android,First sorry for my bad English,I am using default navigation drawer on android studio 1.4 it working fine,but when i click navigation drawer item i want to display activity with tab any one please help me 
here my navigation grawer code

```
 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
        MainFragment fragment=new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {


        GalleryFragment fragment=new GalleryFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

if i am click camera item it will show tabs any one help me how to achive

Comment: try this demo : https://www.codeofaninja.com/2014/02/android-navigation-drawer-example.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this demo : [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

Comment: Link-only answers aren't encouraged! Kindly post the useful information directly in your answer, and also link to the original source.